# Exiting a thread in c

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I am currently working on a some C code, very new to C, so apologize if this is a bit basic or a stupid question.

I have the following code which is executed within a thread using `pthread_create()`.

```
if (ps.status == completed)
        {
            LOG(LOG_AUDIO, "evsafewait_sm_play_tone:\tPlay tone complete");
            if (e2)
            {
                LOG(LOG_MUST, "Failed to free tone event. Result: %i", e2);
            }

            pccb->playToneComplete = 1;
            LOG(LOG_AUDIO, "Detatching thread ID %x", manageToneParms->toneManagerThread);
            //pthread_detach(manageToneParms->toneManagerThread);

            int retVal;
            pthread_exit(&retVal);
            LOG(LOG_AUDIO, "THREAD TERMINATED WITH RESULT %i", retVal);
            LOG(LOG_AUDIO, "Freeing memory");

            free(manageToneParms->playToneParms);
            free(manageToneParms);
            return 0;
        }
```

Before the structures are free and the method returns I am trying to exit the thread using `pthread_exit()` but when this is called, everything below it is skipped, no errors are displayed, as far as I can see anyway.

I have tried debugging it with GDB and when `pthread_exit()` is called the next thing it prints out is `siglongjmp`, I have no idea what this is, I don't believe it's in the C code, at least not in the changes that I have been making to it.

How can I exit this thread? I've also tried `pthread_exit(NULL)` and `pthread_kill(threadID, SIGKILL)` but then this kills the whole program not just the thread.

Comment: `pthread_exit` does exactly what it's supposed to do: stop the thread immediately and not execute anything else on the thread. As to exiting the thread, the easiest way to do that is to complete the thread function. In other words, your `return 0` should do the trick. You also need to use `pthread_join` or `pthread_detach` in the main thread to fully get rid of your thread.

Comment: @Arkadiy, That is so obvious now, probably the stupidest question anyone has ever asked on here. I thought the return might have been the case but I wanted to try calling exit explicitly as since I have made my change to the code it seems to have introduced a memory leak, and thought the thread might have something to do with it.]

Comment: The realm of memory leaks becomes far and wide by doing exactly what this is doing; i.e. pthread_exit() is one of those functions i honestly wish didn't exist. A clean runout of the thread proc is always to be strived for, and makes it soooo much easier to ensure things are cleaned up properly code-organization-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_exit()` returns from the thread at the point of the call. Any code after `pthread_exit()` will not be executed.

You should be sure to release any memory allocated in the thread before calling `pthread_exit()`.

Have you tried something like this:?

```
int retVal;

/* free resources -- make sure all resources allocated in thread 
   function are released 
*/
free(manageToneParms->playToneParms);
free(manageToneParms);

LOG(LOG_AUDIO, "THREAD TERMINATED WITH RESULT %i", retVal);
LOG(LOG_AUDIO, "Freeing memory");
pthread_exit(&retVal);
```